# NPM - No license field

Tags: npm

I am trying to use the following command on the integrated terminal on Visual Studio Code:
npm install

However, an error has been displayed. It says, "npm WARN package.json AngularJS2@1.0.0 No license field." What should I do to fix this issue?

Comment: It is only warning, there is nothing to fix

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add a license attribute in your `package.json` file, e.g:

```json
{ 
  "name": "...."
  ...
  "license" : "SEE LICENSE IN <filename>" 
}
```

If you are working on an open source package with an OSI-approved license, use it's identifier from [this list](https://spdx.org/licenses/) as value for the `license` attribute.

Here is the specification of the package.json format: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your package.json:

```
{
    "license" : "MIT" 
}
```

If your software is opensource.

You can have some examples to use on:
https://opensource.org/licenses

Comment: Adding this license line gave me `license should be a valid SPDX license expression` after running `npm install` - npm version 6.14.7. Changing it to just `MIT` or `GPL` fixed things.

Comment: Should be just `MIT`

Answer (score 1):

Just add this to your package.json:

```
{
 "private": true
}
```

Comment: private: true and license: "MIT" still gives the warning