# Why am i getting ENOENT errors while starting my development server?

Tags: reactjs

I created a react app with yarn. It showed me ENOENT errors while starting the development server.

```
C:Users\Dera\reactprojects\rcipe\yarn start
yarn run v1.12.3
warning ..\package.json: No license field
$ react-scripts start
Starting the development server...

events.js:173
     throw er; //Unhandled 'error' event
     ^
Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.one exit``
```

Comment: The first one is not an error but a warning. [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46047552/npm-no-license-field). The issue is from the second one, and still not sure what it is.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked by installing a previous version of npm-scripts.
Try using:

```
npm install react-scripts@2.1.8
```